# There's a tag [listt] which I think is supposed to be [list<t>]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The title says it all really.

I suspect someone tried to create a tag `[list<t>]` but the brackets got stripped out and he got [listt](/questions/tagged/listt)  instead.

Can the tag be renamed ([generic-list](/questions/tagged/generic-list) perhaps?) or should it just be removed?

Comment: Since [generic-list] already exists and is more popular, setting up a synonym seems appropriate...

Comment: @Shog9 - that would work as well ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've gone through and removed the [listt](/questions/tagged/listt) tag from the questions it was on, and replaced them all with [generic-list](/questions/tagged/generic-list).  I didn't create a synonym, since it was only 38 questions, so it didn't seem to be systemic enough to warrant one.